# Puppet - Permission denied on site.pp

Tags: puppet

While doing "sudo puppet agent -t" on puppet agent I am getting below error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Permission denied - /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

As per the error it seems like my site.pp in my puppet master has not been set correctly, but I checked all the permissions but all seems to be good.

Are there other reasons that I could get this error on my puppet agents?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? maybe share the perms of site.pp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The puppetmaster process is the one attempting to access `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`. The correct ownership depends on whether you're running through WEBrick or Apache. Make sure that the puppetmaster user can access the site.pp file. Try changing to the puppetmaster user and make sure you can access the file.

Also, it could be SELinux causing the access problem, if you're using a RedHat based distro.